# How to change a variable value through function in quasar?

Tags: quasar-framework, quasar

I am trying to change the value of showText using function toggleText., But its not changing through the function.

```
let showText = ref('')
const toggleText = function (idx){          
  showText = idx
  return showText
}
return {
  MYITEMS,
  toggleText,
  showText,    
}
```

How can i change it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

```js
<script setup>
const showText = ref('')

function toggleText(idx)
{
  showText.value = idx
}
</script>
```